# minecraft launcher wont open said that it was moved asks:if you whant to delete this shortcut

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

please help wont open tried evry thing

Answer (score 3):

This isn't an issue with Minecraft, actually. Your shortcut is linked to a file location that doesn't exist anymore. You need to make a new shortcut or correct the existing one.

Answer (score -2):

If you have tried everything, then the only thing is to reinstall Minecraft.

- **Delete All traces of Minecraft on your computer** (this includes launcher and sub files)
- **Reinstall Minecraft from minecraft.net**

Comment: Please note that you will lose your saved information with this solution